# XSLT choose selecting wrong value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

When `myNode` equals the string `none`, my choose statement will return 29 and not 99.

If I remove the test for the string `site-deploy`, the choose statement will return 99.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="myNode = 'site-deploy'"><xsl:text>29</xsl:text></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="myNode = 'none'"><xsl:text>99</xsl:text></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>100</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your XML in this case? Is it the case you actually have more than one `myNode` in your XML? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what it was, I had not anticipated multiple `myNode`. Feel free to submit a reply and and I'll mark it as the answer. Not sure why I hadn't thought of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have multiple `myNode` elements in your XML under the same parent. For example

```
<nodes>
   <myNode>none</myNode>
   <myNode>site-deploy</myNode>
</nodes>
```

Now, when you do a test of the form `myNode = 'site-deploy'`, what that actually does is check if there is any node called `myNode` that has the text "site-deploy". In other words, it checks all `myNode` elements, not just the first one.

How you resolve it depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example, maybe something like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="myNode">
  <myNode>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'site-deploy'"><xsl:text>29</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'none'"><xsl:text>99</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>100</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </myNode>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note if you did just want to check the first `myNode`, you would do `myNode[1] = 'site-deploy'`